# Is there a general tendency among East Asian languages toward simple syllable structure?

Tags: phonology, cross-linguistic, phonotactics, sprachbund

I've noticed that several languages of East Asia and the Pacific islands like Japanese, Chinese, and Hawaiian, have much stricter rules governing phonotactics than languages in other parts of the world.

Is this a legitimate trend, or have I just not been looking at the right languages?

And if it is legitimate, are there any possible reasons for it?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of Chinese as having simple syllable structure, what with tone, fricatives as nucleus, medials, etc., but Polynesian languages do tend to have relatively simple syllable structures.

Comment: If you think this only happens in East Asia, try comparing the syllable structure of English with Proto-Germanic with Proto-Indo-European…

If you're interested in this topic, you might like this book: http://www.amazon.com/Language-Complexity-Evolving-Evolution-ebook/dp/B002FU5NSM .  There's an article by Walter Bisang on East Asia.

Comment: Japanese syllables are very simple but Chinese syllables are possibly only simple if you mean not much in the way of consonant clusters. If you try pronouncing each Chinese syllable with its combinations of vowels and tones you might not find that a simple task to achieve. Maori, Samoan, Tahitian, and Tongan are comparably simple to Japanese. Korean is at least a little more complex than Japanese. Burmese, Khmer, Lao, Thai, and perhaps especially Vietnamese are probably all more complex than Chinese. Indonesian, Malay, and Tagalog are a bit more complex than Japanese. Can you be more specific?

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://wals.info/feature/12A?s=20&z1=3000&z3=2999&z2=2998&tg_format=map&v1=cfff&v2=cf6f&v3=cd00 It looks like many IE languages have complex syllable structure. Comparing to other non-IE regions, I don't really find East Asia that unusual.

Comment: What is an East Asian language? Languages in the Russian Far East, like Nivkh or Itelmen can have very complex syllable structure.

Comment: "East Asian" is not a linguistically meaningful term since most of the languages belong to unrelated families.

Comment: In Geography/politics/travel "East Asia" usually means Japan, Korea, and China. But since the OP also brings up Pacific Islands and specifically Hawaii I suppose this commonsense definition is out the window ... Japanese and Korean have very similar structure but are not believed to be related in the majority view. There is the Sinosphere influence, countries whose languages were influenced greatly by Chinese, mostly by having formerly used Classical Chinese as a written lingua franca. This would then include Vietnamese but not Hawaiian ...

Comment: @EricDong: While the languages are not related, it's certainly possible for Sprachbunds to include similar syllable structures across unrelated languages.

Comment: Also, consider the complex onsets in Tibetan and in various reconstructed phonologies of Old Chinese.

Answer (score 3):

Recently, the [World Phonotactics Database](http://phonotactics.anu.edu.au/) was launched. While I've noticed some errors in languages I'm familiar with, it may be useful to check there.

First off, is there a trend across languages in terms of syllable structure? To start with, let's look at how many consonants can be in an onset. Their sample contains 2,338 languages. Of these, 2 do not allow onsets, 1,363 allow for at most 1 consonant in their onset position, 727 allow for at most 2 onset consonants, 229 allow for at most 3 consonants, 15 allow for at most 4 consonants, and 2 allow for at most 6 consonants (note that they have no languages in their sample with at most 5 onset consonants).

Let's also look at how many consonants can be in a coda. They again sample from 2,338 languages. Of these, 485 languages do not allow for coda consonants, 1,373 allow for at most 1 coda consonant, 358 allow for at most 2 coda consonants, 107 allow for at most 3 coda consonants, 12 allow for at most 4 coda consonants, and 3 allow for at most 5 coda consonants.

With this in mind, I think it's likely that what we're seeing in the rest of the world--where "familiar" languages allow for complex onsets and codas--is actually a result confirmation bias. Indo-European languages, for instance, with the exception of highly divergent languages like English or Russian, really only allow for at most 2 or 3 onset consonants (2s include Armenian, Spanish, and Punjabi; and 3s include Albanian, Irish, and Lithuanian).

In most of the world's languages, a CV structure is preferred. This is, as far as I'm aware, a very old typological generalization. [The Universals Archive](http://typo.uni-konstanz.de/archive/nav/browse.php?number=687) cites Jakobson and Hale (1956) as the first statement of this structure being a linguistic universal.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is you might be oversimplifying the facts. We have no data on Hawaiian or other ancient languages of Pacific phylum yet, but here are some points proving that at least Chinese and Japanese do not fall under the same category:

1. The Chinese is basically monosyllable, CV, V, Vc or CVc-structured language while Japanese is a polysyllabic, mora-structured language.
2. The Japanese used to have vowel harmony.
3. Some languages of the area (Thai, Burmese and tribal languages of China) have different prosodic structures, including C2C1V- initial syllables.

There are languages like Finnish or ancient Kretian sharing the same predominant CV- structure for syllable like Hawaiian or Japanese (although Hawaiianan word may also have +VV+ syllable structure), but this does not mean these languages are related by their syllable-structuring principles.

Comment: While I agree with your conclusion, I think your points 1) and 2) are irrelevant to the question (which was about _syllable_ structure). And the OP nowhere suggested that the languages in question were related.

Comment: The OP unites the languages under a category of 'having much stricter rules'. But the rules for Chinese and Japanese are different (I am sure the TS is aware of difference between Chinese and Japanese). Vowel harmony is more typical for Paleo-Asiatic / Uralic / Altaic languages than for the languages of the East Asia and Pacific, adding one more rule to the sylable formation principle. In some Paleo-Asiatic and Native American languages there is either a consonant harmony, or both consonant-vowel harmony as well, but these are not languages of the area mentioned in OP.

Comment: ...and therefore the (old) Japanese language with its vowel harmony might had created its syllables by entirely different rules (we have no data on moras in AJ anyway), these rules being closer to those applied at the outside area than to the area mentioned at the OP.

Comment: But vowel harmony is by definition a super-syllabic constraint. It does not add any "rule to the syllable formation principle", only to selection of syllables.

Comment: I'm curious as to what your second sentence means, where you say 'we have no data on Hawaiian or other ancient languages of Pacific phylum...'??

Comment: Korean as well as Japanese is supposed to have formerly had vowel harmony, so that's two East Asian languages not accepted as related but definitely in a Sprachbund.

Comment: @Colin Fine : vowel harmony p.l.u.s. consonant harmony

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut: If you have joined the discussion as a person having some more data on [ancient] Hawaiian or other ancient languages of Pacific phylum, pls feel free to share it with us.

Comment: I've joined the discussion to seek clarification of part of your answer. In particular, I didn't understand your description of Hawaiian as an '...ancient language of Pacific phylum', but your comment suggests you meant to refer to 'Ancient Hawiian', as opposed to currently-spoken Hawaiian, is that right? But I don't understand your reference to 'ancient languages of Pacific phylum'--can you explain what you're talking about, perhaps [proto-Polynesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Polynesian_language)?

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut: Well, maybe the 'phylum' is not the best term to talk about a language union (presumably including some Papuan languages, too). The point is that we do not know much about the linguistical history of the area and its linguistic connections; the have just theories.

Comment: We do know a lot about the [historical linguistics of Austronesian languages](http://anthro.unige.ch/~sanchez-mazas/phm/16ROSS_CHAP06-OK.pdf), especially the Oceanic group. Proto-Oceanic has been worked out in some detail as has proto-Polynesian. I'm not sure why you mention Papuan languages and a 'language union'.

Comment: @Gaston Ümlaut : I wouldn't say that a 21-page-long article contains a lot of information about historical linguistics of Austronesian languages, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It does, I think, present a pretty decent overview. And the 4 page bibliography points to a lot of information on Austronesian historical linguistics, and that's just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: The existence of vowel harmony in Old Japanese is by no means a certainty—rather, it is hotly debated, and no consensus has been reached. Also, it is not clear whether you are talking about Modern Finnish, but if you are, it is quite a stretch to say that its syllable has a “predominant CV structure”, considering the vast number of CVC syllables that are found in Finnish.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Thank you for your interestiung response. The CV structure in modern Finnish can be easily noticed when considering most of Fenno-Ugric by their origin words in their initial forms. The CVC syllables are mostly results of word-formation.

Comment: In other words, by ‘Finnish’, you were really more accurately talking about Fennic/Fenno-Ugric. In that case, I agree completely.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Besides, there are almost no -V-ending words in modern Finnish vocabulary (in their initial forms).

Comment: How do you mean, “in their initial forms”? There are hundreds of nouns whose most basic forms (nom.sg.) end in vowels—in fact, the majority of nouns do (even counting the e/k-stems that historically ended in consonants) …

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet In any form as given by dictionaries. Otherwise, you contradict what you have said about Fennic/Fenno-Ugric.

Comment: Erm no, not really. There are plenty of both vowel- and consonant-final nouns in Modern Finnish, but the vowel-final ones are more numerous. Proto-Fenno-Ugric was more heavily CV-based than Modern Finnish, and it makes sense to speak of a “predominant CV structure” for that stage. The same does not hold true for Modern Finnish.

Comment: -VC nouns in Modern Finnish are mostly derivates from 'initial' nouns, even  (or especially) those ending in -inen.

Comment: I'm also confused by the comment that we "don't know much about the linguistic history of the Pacific". It's just not true. Sure, untangling the history of the so-called Papuan languages is just in its infancy, but we know a lot about the history of the Austronesian language family. See [Blust 2009](http://pacling.anu.edu.au/materials/Blust2013Austronesian.pdf) or [Lynch, Ross, and Crowley 2011](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Oceanic_Languages.html?id=xG1Q0alrpq8C), for instance.